# PHP Class Extends and Objects

Tags: php, class, extends

I have a results.php and 2 classes, Dog which extends Pet class. The "fullDescription" method call is just returning null for the results (eg: "Description: Your pet is a named .")

What am I missing?

results.php:

```
    <?php
    //include('_includes/pet.class.php');
    include("_includes/dog.class.php");

?>
<?php

// COLLECT THE VALUES FROM THE FORM
$petType = $_POST["petType"];
$petName = $_POST["petName"];

// CREATE A NEW INSTANCE OF THE CORRECT TYPE
if ($petType == "dog")
{
    $myPet = new Dog();
    $myPet->breed = Dog::randomBreed();
}
else
{
    $myPet = new Cat();
    $myPet->breed = randomBreed();
}

// ASSIGN THE VALUE FROM THE FORM TO THE name PROPERTY OF THE PET OBJECT
$myPet->name = $petName;
$myPet->descriptor = Pet::randomDescriptor();
$myPet->color = Pet::randomColor();

?>

<div class="basic-grey">

<h1>Here's the information about your pet:</h1>

<p>Pet Name:  <?php echo $myPet->name; ?></p>
<p>Pet Name:  <?php echo $myPet->breed; ?></p>
<p>Pet Name:  <?php echo $myPet->color; ?></p>
<p>Pet Name:  <?php echo $myPet->descriptor; ?></p>
<p>Description: <?php echo $myPet->fullDescription(); ?> </p>
```

Pet Class

```
<?php

class Pet
{

    // DEFINE YOUR CLASS PROPERTIES HERE
    private $name;
    private $descriptor;
    private $color;
    private $breed;

    ///////// Getters Setters /////////
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setDescriptor($descriptor) {
        $this->descriptor = $descriptor;
    }
    public function getDescriptor() {
        return $this->descriptor;
    }

    public function setColor($color) {
        $this->color = $color;
    }
    public function getColor() {
        return $this->color;
    }

    public function setBreed($breed) {
        $this->breed = $breed;
    }
    public function getBreed() {
        return $this->breed;
    }

    // DEFINE YOUR METHODS HERE
    public function fullDescription()
    {
        return "Your pet is a $this->descriptor $this->color $this->breed named $this->name.";
        //echo $myPet->getName();
    }

    public static function randomDescriptor()
    {
        // SET UP AN ARRAY OF VALUES
        $input = array("stinky", "huge", "tiny", "lazy", "lovable");

        // RETURN A SINGLE RANDOM ELEMENT FROM THE ARRAY
        return array_rand(array_flip($input), 1);
    }

    public static function randomColor()
    {
        // SET UP AN ARRAY OF VALUES
        $input = array("tan", "brown", "black", "white", "spotted");

        // RETURN A SINGLE RANDOM ELEMENT FROM THE ARRAY
        return array_rand(array_flip($input), 1);
    }
}
?>
```

Dog Class

```
<?php
include('pet.class.php');

//////////// DOG CLASS //////////////
class Dog extends Pet
{public static function randomBreed()
    {
        // SET UP AN ARRAY OF VALUES
        $input = array("german shepherd", "dachsund", "retriever", "labradoodle", "bulldog");

        // RETURN A SINGLE RANDOM ELEMENT FROM THE ARRAY
        return array_rand(array_flip($input), 1);
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Where do you define `Cat` class? Maybe the true problem lies in that it never actually calls `new Dog()` but instead it calls the `else` of your condition, which is `new Cat()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the following lines,

```
$myPet->breed = Dog::randomBreed();
```

and

```
$myPet->name = $petName;
$myPet->descriptor = Pet::randomDescriptor();
$myPet->color = Pet::randomColor();
```

You're trying to access `private` properities of class `Pet`. Plus, you didn't the assign property values using setter methods. **The solution** would be like this:

You cannot access `private` properties of a class from it's child class, or outside of the parent class. First declare them as `protected` properties:

```
class Pet
{

    // DEFINE YOUR CLASS PROPERTIES HERE
    protected $name;
    protected $descriptor;
    protected $color;
    protected $breed;

    // your code

}
```

and then on **results.php** page change those lines in the following way:

```
// your code

if ($petType == "dog")
{
    $myPet = new Dog();
    $myPet->setBreed(Dog::randomBreed());
}
else
{
    $myPet = new Cat();
    $myPet->setBreed(Cat::randomBreed());
}
$myPet->setName($petName);
$myPet->setDescriptor(Pet::randomDescriptor());
$myPet->setColor(Pet::randomColor());
echo $myPet->fullDescription();
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that since private properties are inaccessible to a subclass, when the OP was making assignments like `$myPet->name = $petName;` he was creating new _public_ properties on the class `Dog` itself. If the property `name` in the parent class was protected he'd have seen a fatal error "Cannot access protected property".

Comment: @DarraghEnright  you are right. i understoodt from yuor explanation why $myPet->descriptor; returns value when called from application  and don't returns anything from class method -    https://eval.in/563116

Comment: @DarraghEnright you'right. Since `private` properties cannot be accessible from child class, all the properties should be declared `protected` to make them accessible from child class. Good catch. :-)

Comment: No problem. Great answer :)

Comment: Thanks that hit it right on the head. Appreciate the time you took to answer! Thanks crew!

Comment: @NickEllis Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

In your `Pet` class you've set your properties to `private` which means they cannot be manipulated *publicly* (from within the application), and *only* from within the class in which they are set (`Pet` in this case). Any reason for that?

Set them to `public`:

```
public $name;
public $descriptor;
public $color;
public $breed;
```

Here's the manual on [OOP visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). Discusses the differences between *public*, *protected*, *private*.